# Retina display Implemetation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can anybody tell me the step-by-step procedure to implement Retina Display in my iphone application.

Comment: Step 1: Open X-Code. End of Steps.

Comment: Step 2: Ask SO to do it for you

Comment: Do you mean Retina Display elements such as icons and other UI features?

Comment: FYI Guys, Don't waste a downvote, he's only got 4 rep, educate don't punish!

Comment: You need to be quite a bit more specific about what your problem is, asking to "write me a guide" isn't quite how this site works.

Comment: read the answer given by @Jeremy1026

Comment: @DanielHanly Downvotes are not a measure of punishment but education. Also, they are a way to make SO useful to many, not only the OP.

Comment: @Madhuri did you even bother to read the Apple docs?

Comment: the problem is, the iPhone 4 and 4S **have already** Retina Display, so to those devices you don't have to implement it. the older devices (2G, 3G, 3Gs) have no Retina Display, but who the hell wants to equipped a Retina Display manually for them? just buy a new phone with Retina Display, it is the easiest way!

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I'd be a lot less likely to return to a site if my first question was downvoted so much. What we need to do is give the OP a chance to improve the quality of their question before hitting them with downvotes. It's the best way to teach correct function and format. If they prove unresponsive to efforts to improve then fine, downvote, but I believe they should have a chance first.

Comment: @DanielHanly Madhuri is a registered member since two months. He made three posts in this time. He probably *read* a lot more posts. I'm quite sure he's able to understand why he gets downvotes and how to fix the issues with his post. And if not, he probably just does not care.

Answer (score 2):

Create your images in standard and double size. Give them the same name, but with the double size having a suffix of '@2x'. So for example `homebutton.png` and `homebutton@2x.png`.

The OS is able to handle loading the correct image for you so long as both are in your bundle and you reference them correctly. When appling your image within the app (either in code or in interface builder) simple reference the image as `homebutton`. That tells iOS to load the @2x for retina devices and the non-@2x for standard resolution displays.

It is a very simple procedure, if you have any other questions let me know and I'll do my best to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about image resolutions within your app, then add another image (with twice the resolution) with the @2x as part of the filename.
For example, image.png would have a partner called image@2x.png.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what kind of steps you need to take to optimize your application for the retina display these articles will provide a detailed explaination on how you do that:

[Designing for Retina display, part one](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/)

[Designing for Retina display, part two](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/)